# Problema al guardar valor de spinner

Tags: php, mysql, android, spinner

**Buenas, tengo un spinner que carga valores de `MySql` y así lo hago:

```
public void listaZonas() {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://pagina.com/zonas.php",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String zona = jsonObject1.getString("nombreZona");
                            zonasClaseArrayList.add(new ZonasClase(zona));
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<ZonasClase> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ZonasClase>(CargaPrecios.this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, zonasClaseArrayList);
                        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        zonas.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(CargaPrecios.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este `PHP` para guardar los valores:

```
$precioMinimo = $_POST[precioMinimo];
$precioMaximo = $_POST[precioMaximo];
$fkZona = $_POST[fkZona];
$fechaCargaPrecio = $_POST[fechaCargaPrecio];
$fkUsuario = $_POST[fkUsuario];
$sql = "INSERT INTO cargaPrecioPapas (precioMinimo, precioMaximo, fkZona, fechaCargaPrecio, fkUsuario) 
             VALUES ($precioMinimo, '$precioMaximo', '$fkZona', '$fechaCargaPrecio', '$fkUsuario');";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
          echo "si.";
    } else {
          echo "Error: " . $sql . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Y así lo guardo:

```
private void insertarPreciosMinimo(final int valor){
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(precio.getText().toString())) {
        precio.setError("Por favor, ingrese un precio.");
        precio.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    final int zona = Integer.valueOf(zonas.getSelectedItemPosition());
    Calendar fechaActual = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mesActual = fechaActual.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    final String fecha = fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + mesActual + "/"
            + fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    final int idUsuario = new PreferenciaIdUsuario(CargaPrecios.this).traerValorGuardado();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://pagina.com/insertpreciosminimo.php", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if(response.contains("si")){
                Toast.makeText(CargaPrecios.this,"Registro correcto.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cerrar();
            }else{
                Log.d("TAG", "onResponse: " + response);
                Toast.makeText(CargaPrecios.this,"Ha surgido un error al ingresar el precio.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()  {
            Map<String,String>parms=new HashMap<String, String>();
            parms.put("precioMinimo", String.valueOf(valor));
            parms.put("precioMaximo", "100");
            parms.put("fkZona", String.valueOf(zona));
            parms.put("fechaCargaPrecio", fecha);
            parms.put("fkUsuario", String.valueOf(idUsuario));
            return parms;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

El problema es que en determinados ítems del spinner sale este error:

> ```
> INSERT INTO cargaPrecioPapas (precioMinimo, precioMaximo, fkZona, fechaCargaPrecio, fkUsuario) 
>     VALUES ('15', '100', '0', '22/11/2020', '1'); 
>     Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails `u256520734_ProyectoPapri`.`cargaPrecioPapas`, CONSTRAINT `fkCargaPrecioZonas` FOREIGN KEY (`fkZona`) REFERENCES `zonas` (`idZona`))
> ```

Nótese que en la sentencia `VALUES` se imprime el valor **'0'** en **fkZona**.
¿Alguien me podría decir cómo se hace de manera correcta?

Este es mi botón para guardar los datos:

```
    guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                int valorIngresado = 0;
                valorIngresado = Integer.parseInt(precio.getText().toString());
                final int valor = valorIngresado;
                if(valorIngresado > 100){
                    insertarPreciosMaximo(valor);
                }else{
                    insertarPreciosMinimo(valor);
                }
            }catch (NumberFormatException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

He tratado de controlar el elemento seleccionado de la siguiente manera pero sigue devolviendo el valor 0 (cero):

```
    guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int zona = Integer.valueOf(zonas.getSelectedItemPosition());
            int posicion = zonasClaseArrayList.get(zona).getId();
            Toast.makeText(CargaPrecios.this, String.valueOf(posicion), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Log.d("pos", "onItemSelected: " + posicion);
        }
    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Del mismo modo, también he intentado hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
    zonas.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
            guardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int posicion = zonasClaseArrayList.get(position).getId();
                    Toast.makeText(CargaPrecios.this, String.valueOf(posicion), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Y me sigue devolviendo el valor 0:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si llega un valor `0` que no debería llegar, el problema está en Android, debes controlar, donde recoges los datos, que éstos sean válidos. Por ejemplo, obligando a que el usuario escriba valores válidos, no admitiendo `0`, valores en blanco, etc. dejando desactivado un eventual botón `Enviar` hasta que no esté todo OK. No deberías lanzarte a la aventura de mandar datos al servidor sin haberlos verificado primero. Otro grave problema que veo en tu código es el peligro de la *Inyección SQL*. Pero ese es otro tema.

Comment: Pues, la verdad que he probado controlar el valor del item seleccionado del spinner pero no consigo dar con la solución. Haga lo que haga siempre queda en 0. @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿En qué parte del código controlas eso? Muestrala en la pregunta. ¿Qué depuraciones estás haciendo del valor?

Comment: He actualizado el la pregunta @A.Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` significa que estas enviando un valor a una columna que no existe en la tabla referenciada.

En este caso estas enviando el indice de la zona segun como lo agregas al spinner, en vez de enviar el id de la zona que es lo que la columna `fkZona` espera.

Cuando selecionas la primera zona en el `Spinner`, el metodo `zonas.getSelectedItemPosition()` te retornara el indice 0 y es casi seguro que no tienes una zona con el id 0 en la tabla `zonas`(o como se llame), por lo que el foreign key te lanza el error de que no existe una zona con ese id.

Busca la manera de guadar la lista de zonas con su id para que al momento de guardar la información puedas obtener el id de la zona. Por lo que cambiarias:

```
final int zona = Integer.valueOf(zonas.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Con por ejemplo:

```
int indexZonaSeleccionada = zonas.getSelectedItemPosition();
final int zona = zonasClaseArrayList.get(indexZonaSeleccionada).getId();
//...
```

Comment: De hecho, unas de las cosas que probé es lo que mencionas pero sigue lanzando el mismo error